# Webpack process.env vars in React

Tags: webpack

In Browserify / Gulp world, I used to use envify to 'fill in' the process.env vars in the React code. How does one achieve this in the Webpack world?

Looking at this doc
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

I'm setting up..

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'views/index.handlebars',
      filename: 'views/index.handlebars'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '[name].js.map',
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['HEROKU', 'HEROKU_PREFIX', 'LANG', 'NODE_ENV'])
  ]
```

in my webpack config.

The process.env vars are still not being 'filled in'

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an object instead:

```
plugins: [
...
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
        'HEROKU': 'Heroku',
        'HEROKU_PREFIX': 'Prefix_', 
        'LANG': 'English', 
        'NODE_ENV': 'development'
    })
]
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: The values in your example are hardcoded though. Trying to pick them up from .env file. I'm following the Webpack examples, but no suprise — Webpack is not working.

Comment: You are using an array in your code sample. Did you try passing the values as an object? like new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin( { .. } )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to install the lib [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) (just to build your project). It loads your `.env` file and after that, you can generate an object with all the data and set in 'process.env' variable through the `DefinePlugin`.

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

let env;
// load your .env file
const getEnv = () => {
  if (!env) {
    env = dotenv.config({ path: `${process.cwd()}/config/dev.env`}).parsed;
  }
  return env;
};
 
// generate an object with all env variables 
const envKeys = Object.keys(getEnv()).reduce((prev, next) => {
  prev[`${next}`] = JSON.stringify(getEnv()[next]);
  return prev;
}, {'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')});



//webpack conf

module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    // apply all your env var to process.env variable
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': envKeys
    }),
  ],
}
```